# nlog old archive files aren't deleted: archiveNumbering=Date,archiveOldFileOnStartup,maxArchiveFiles

Tags: c#, date, archive, nlog

NLog Version 4.3.6

This target creates a logfile in the log directory in the following format `Trace_2016-08-03.log` the logfile is moved on startup to the archive directory with a name like `Trace_2016-08-03_11h33m32s_743ms.log` however old archive files aren't deleted (maxArchiveFiles=2). Can anybody help me on this. I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.

```
<target name="AsyncTrace" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
  <target name="TraceFile" xsi:type="File"
    layout="${time} ${level} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
    fileName="${localLogHome}/Trace_${shortDate}.log" 
    archiveFileName="${localLogHome}/Archive/Trace_{#}.log"
    archiveNumbering="Date"
    archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd_HH\hmm\mss\s_fff\m\s"
    archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
    maxArchiveFiles="2"
      />
</target>
```

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: Try to see this issue on GitHub : https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/309. It's old, but maybe this issue is not yet solved.

Comment: @IgorDamiani this problem should be resolved. If you look at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/643

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems with this configuration.

1. The fileName (of the normal logFile) contains a Date.
   see https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/354
2. The archive fails to recognize existing archive files when archiveDateFormat contains escapechars like in my example so `yyyy-MM-dd_HH\hmm\mss\s_fff\m\s` was transformed to `yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss`

   ```
   <target name="AsyncTrace" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
       <target name="TraceFile" xsi:type="File"
           layout="${time} ${level} ${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
           fileName="${localLogHome}/Trace.log" 
           archiveFileName="${localLogHome}/Archive/Trace_{#}.log"
           archiveNumbering="Date"
           archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd_HH.mm.ss"
           archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"
           maxArchiveFiles="1"
     />
   ```

Comment: I have the same problem, but with a different config : <target name="file" xsi:type="File"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${message}"
            fileName="${LogDir}/${LogDay}.log"
            maxArchiveFiles="30"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence"
            archiveAboveSize="1048576"
            archiveFileName="${LogDir}/${LogDay}-archive{##}.log"
            keepFileOpen="false"
            encoding="utf-8" />